# Hudson on Windows not detecting CVS checkins

Tags: windows, build, continuous-integration, hudson, cvs

I'm getting odd behaviour from my Hudson setup on Windows when monitoring a CVS repository; access is via extssh.  After checking in a change to the repository, if I run "cvs status filename.ext" against the changed file in Hudson's working copy, I can see that the repository has a newer revision.  However, Hudson (which is set to poll the CVS repository at a fixed interval) does not see the change when it does its cvs update.

Any ideas what might be going on ?  I can't see anything useful in the Hudson logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the clocks of both servers (cvs and hudson). This is the usual problem if you can't checkout from svn.

Comment: Thanks, Peter - the CVS server was half an hour ahead of the Hudson machine, so it turned out that checkins were being detected after all, but not until after a 30 minute delay.  So much for continuous integration !